# Deploying existing webapp using Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

There is a web app that I need to deploy, and was wondering what the best way to do this would be. I'm using a Mac OSx with eclipse indigo. Also, this application needs to be imported into the eclipse workspace first. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the eclipse menu, there's an import option. Select it, choose your app, and that should be enough.

If you want to just deploy the app without eclipse, simply place the `.war` file in the tomcat directory (the root directory for its apps), and when it loads, it will automatically extract it.

Comment: thanks eran! however, compiling the source as a Java application returns a Launch Error with the following message "Selection does not contain a main type". any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your project is a 'dynamic web project', you're running the project and not one of the files (in the project tree, right-click the project name and run that), and when you're running it, you're doing it with a server (and with the correct tomcat that you have installed).
Otherwise, google this error, there are many people who have already encountered it...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Eran Zimmerman answer, you could just make symbolic link to your `.war` file into deploy directory (it will be automatic extraction when `.war` file changed).